# Page is jumping to top when clicking on thumb images

Tags: jquery, jquery-slider

I've image slider,

```
<div class="slider">
  <div id="image_large_1">
      <img src="../1.png" alt="">   
  </div>
  <div id="image_large_2">
      <img src="../2.png" alt="">   
  </div>
</div>

<!-- Slider close,thumb start -->

<div class="thumbs_div">
  <div id="thumb_1">
     <img src="../1_t.png" alt="" id="thumb_1">   
  </div>
  <div id="thumb_2">
     <img src="../2_t.png" alt="" id="thumb_2">   
  </div>
</div>
```

When user clicks on thumb image then its corresponding large size image will display in **slider div**. Everything is working fine but when I click on thumb image then page is jumping to top,what might be the problem ? following is the jQuery code.

```
$("div[id^=image_large_]:gt(0)").hide();
$("div.thumb_div img").click(function(){

       div_id = $(this).attr('id').substring('thumb_'.length);
       $("div[id^=image_large_]").hide();
       $("div#image_large_"+div_id).fadeIn('slow');

    });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your `slider` div does not have specified dimensions, then it collapses when the `image_large_*` divs are hidden by this line:

```
 $("div[id^=image_large_]").hide();
```

With the result that content lower down the page will move up will jump up when `.hide()` completes.

Try giving the large image container divs the same dimensions as the images they contain.

Comment: @bob12: Sorry,I've modified how you have suggested but still facing same issue.

Comment: @Mahesh.D - Yes, see edited answer above - it should be the `slider` div that needs to have dimensions specified.